# Will I receive pending messages after I reactivate my account on new phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My Samsung Galaxy S3 was damaged by water and I now have a new Galaxy S4. I have reinstalled WhatsApp on the new phone. However I do know that I have messages sent by others that I have not received, they are pending.

Will I receive these messages? I have the same SIM card and there was a two week period between old and new phone.

Comment: "*I have messages sent that I have not received*", did you mean "I have messages **sent by others** that I have not received"? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense (you don't receive the message you sent)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yup looks like that's what is meant here(others sent him)

Answer (score 1):

You will receive any messages that were sent  after the S3 died & activation of WhatsApp on your new phone.

However, any messages you had received on your old phone & didn't read cannot be received again.

Answer (score -1):

No, you won't receive them, because there is no place to store them except of your phone. Since you haven't been registered, you won't receive these messages. That's my case when installing a new ROM to my phone.