# Recover pending WhatsApp messages sent to old phone number

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

I have WhatsApp on my Android phone. I changed from number A to number B and did not notify contacts. Later, some contacts told me that they had sent me messages on WhatsApp to phone number A, and I did not receive them. They see the messages as having only one tick, which means that they are on WhatsApp's servers. I would like to recover those pending messages, especially from the other contacts who didn't tell me that they had sent messages.

I changed the number on the WhatsApp app back to number A, but still, those messages do not appear on the phone.

Does the encryption key change when I change numbers? If so, those messages are indecipherable, even if the WhatsApp server does send them.

If not, has anyone managed to recover pending messages?

Note: this question is different from [Will I receive pending messages after I reactivate my account on new phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108476/will-i-receive-pending-messages-after-i-reactivate-my-account-on-new-phone) because the action is reversible (I can change phone numbers) and I know that the top answer does not work (I have pending messages that I did not receive).

Comment: "I tried changing the number on the phone back to number A" does this mean you have switched SIM card or does this mean you have reconfigured Whatsapp to use the old number?

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I reconfigured WhatsApp and I edited the question.